# aspnet Core Authentication error - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-core

Is anyone else getting this error?

I am trying to get Authentication working in aspnet core 1.1 for OAuth providers.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder encoder, IOptions sharedOptions, IOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder encoder, IOptions sharedOptions, IOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Comment: Did you try `Install-Package System.Net.Http` ?

Comment: Yes. Installed 4.3.1 - still broken. Package hell